# Не подключается библиотека

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. Не могу понять, почему не срабатывает библиотека. Файлы подключил, инициализировал, в консоли выдает эту ошибку Uncaught ReferenceError: AOS is not defined
Ссылка на библиотеку https://github.com/michalsnik/aos
Ниже прикрепил фрагмент кода, а также все подключенные файлы

```js
AOS.init();
```

```html
<!-- Styles -->
<link href="bower_components/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bower_components/aos/dist/aos.css">


<!-- SERVICES -->
<div class="container text-center services">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 ">
      <div class="card item" data-aos="fade-zoom-in">
        <img src="css/img/services image/Shape-1.png">
        <h4>Duis aute irure</h4>
        <p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupi datat non it proident, sunt in cul</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 ">
      <div class="card" data-aos="fade-zoom-in">
        <img src="css/img/services image/Shape-2.png">
        <h4>Duis aute irure</h4>
        <p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupi datat non it proident, sunt in cul</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 ">
      <div class="card" data-aos="fade-zoom-in">
        <img src="css/img/services image/Shape-3.png">
        <h4>Duis aute irure</h4>
        <p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupi datat non it proident, sunt in cul</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<!-- SCRIPTS -->
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/aos/dist/aos.js"></script>
```

Comment: видимо это происходит потому что вы подключаете библиотеку после того как подключили `js/main.js` и пытаетесь обратится к ней из него. попробуйте поменять местами

Comment: да, вы правы, спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

видимо это происходит потому что вы подключаете `библиотеку` после того как подключили `js/main.js` и пытаетесь обратится к ней из него. попробуйте `поменять местами`.